# Bitwise arithmetic, How can x*x<0?

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, integer-arithmetic

I'm looking over reviewing for an exam involving bitwise operations and found a useful page with a problem that I am confused about. 
http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15213-f05/lectures/class03.txt

The specific problem is at the bottom of the page under 'Puzzles'. Given a signed integer x, and assuming a 32 bit word size and 2's complement how can we show that

x*x <0?

They list 50000 as a possible solution, and I am not sure why or how that works.

I tried starting small considering 3*3 = 9, 0011 * 0011 = 1001.
Moved to 2 nibbles, 0010 0001 * 0010 0010 = 34*34 =  1156 = 100 [1000 0100]
And thought I found a pattern of increasing the intervals between my 1 bits but it does not work when I got closer to 32 bits.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 2's complement, the most-significant bit denotes the sign of the number.  If you do an arithmetic operation with positive numbers that ends up carrying into that specific bit, you'll end up with a negative number.

For example:

```
         50 000 = 0b00000000000000001100001101010000
50 000 * 50 000 = 0b10010101000000101111100100000000
```

The most significant bit is set to 1, so now the resulting number is considered negative when interpreted as a *signed value*.

Here's a quick demo of the above idea in action: https://ideone.com/TU049L

Comment: Thank you, I was originally trying to convert 2500000000 into 32 bit signed binary which is out of range, rather than analyze binary result.